# why the npm url dependencies did not fetch the newest code

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm

I modify a public npm repo source code and now I want to use the modified version by using the github url in `package.json`. Then I change the dependencies in `package.json` like this:

```
"translation.js": "git+ssh://git@github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/translation.js.git#master",
```

After install the dependencies using `npm ci` command, I check the source code from the local project source `node_modules` folder. it seems the npm did not fetch the github newest modified code and still using this legacy code. I also tried this in `package.json`:

```
"translation.js": "jiangxiaoqiang/translation.js#master",
```

still did not work. I also tried to delete the local `translate.js` folder and redownload the dependencies, still did not work. Am I missing something? what should I do to using the url and make it fetch the newest code? The local folder structure look like this:

[image]

should I do some compile before used this repo? I also tried to use command like this:

```
npm install
```

but shows error like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% npm install
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/translation.js.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dolphin/.npm/_logs/2022-01-04T15_17_56_900Z-debug.log
```

my node version is v8.17.0.

Answer (score 0):

I install the dependencies using this command:

```
npm install https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/translation.js.git
```

and the `package.json` look like this:

```
"translation.js": "github:jiangxiaoqiang/translation.js",
```